# py2exe : DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, py2exe

I use py2exe to cenvert my script to .exe file. It work fine but when i copy the **dist** folder which contain exe file and all related file to another PC. It run failed. The error is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Agent.py", line 6, in <module>
  File "psutil\__init__.pyc", line 146, in <module>
  File "psutil\_pswindows.pyc", line 16, in <module>
  File "psutil\_psutil_windows.pyc", line 12, in <module>
  File "psutil\_psutil_windows.pyc", line 10, in __load
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

But when i check in folder **dist/libary/psutil** those module are there.
It not missing why the error tell me those module couldn't be found ?

Comment: did you ever solve this?